# Adding LogService to my Application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, .net-3.5, singleton

I have an application (Legacy code)

that contains interface `Icomponent` with `save()` methods

and many classes that implement it.

I want to add log after every save().

**updae**:

I had few design ideas:

- Singelton Logger - that will be called after every logged-able action

I think `LogService` is a classic case of singelton, but I read it would be hard for unit-testing.

- Decorator + logger init with Ioc

use the decorator pattern to `Icomponent` with additional `log()` method.

create `LogService` class which is called from each decorator's `log()`

- AOP - aspect orient programming

I read about this a bit, but don't know it.

Is it applicable to c# ?

- What would be your design to that solution?

**update2**

After reading the code, I see there is another layer of interfaces

before the concrete layer. I don't think I should decorate every specific interface. right?

```
I_AComponente : IComponente

I_BComponente : IComponente

A : I_AComponente

B : I_BComponente
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be singleton at all. Consider:

```
public void ComponentDecorator : IComponent
{
    private IComponent component;
    private ILogger logger;

    public ComponentDecorator(IComponent component, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.component = component;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.component.Save();
        this.logger.Log("Some important message");
    }
}
```

Since you'll be injecting decorated components to decorator anyways, might just as well inject logger (which then is rather easy to test). Where `logger` comes from will be irrelevant from unit test perspective.

Also, instead of rolling your own loggers you should check existing ones, like [Apache log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

**Edit**:

The claim that singleton logger is hard to test might come from that fact that singleton in C# will usually be implemented with `static` field somewhere, or static class. Say you had:

```
public static LoggerService
{
    public static Log(string message) { ... }
}
```

Now, in your decorators' methods you'll probably have to do something along those lines:

```
public void Save()
{
    this.component.Save();
    LoggerService.Log("Some important message");
}
```

This makes testing of the `Save` method nearly impossibly, as you have tightly coupled dependency inside your method. It's not that bad if you can configure `LoggerService` for tests not to write to file system (but still, it's rather going around the problem instead of solving it).

In the *inject via interface* that problem is gone naturally. `LoggerService` might still be static class, but it could simply provide non-static loggers (and manage their lifetime/scope). This doesn't make unit testing difficult at all.

Comment: thanks, but yet the logger I pass to all Icomponent implementation's ctors is singleton.

Comment: @EladBenda: it doesn't matter at all. Since it's passed via interface, you can mock it (and that's what's important). How it looks outside of tested class is irrelevant. Being singleton **doesn't** make it hard to test. I've added explanation/example to my post.

Comment: `might still be static class, but it could simply provide non-static loggers` how can it be? static class has only static fields. I can make a static setter.

Comment: @EladBenda: static class might have static methods. And you can return anything you want (as in - non static) from such. Point is, that static singleton class would most likely have to manage created loggers creation and lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! AOP is applicable to C sharp
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/

AOP is a good way to avoid writing Log statements all over your code. Here is an example of how u could implement AOP in your app....however the only drawback in the approach provided on following link is you will also need to configure Castle Windsor
http://ayende.com/blog/3474/logging-the-aop-way

Comment: Thanks. What are the pros and cons of using AOP in C# ?